# How to return data from the child thread

Tags: ios, swift, nsthread

1. As it said in title,how to return data from the child thread
2. please help me to resolve it,thank you very much

.

```
    func showMessage()->String
{
    //sign up 
    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (successed, error) in
        if error == nil
        {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                //load UI
                self.message = ErrorTypeValue.showMessageWithError(error) as String
              })

        }else
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                //load UI
                self.showSuccess = true

                self.message = self.showSuccessMessage()

            })

        }
    }

    return self.message!
}
```

Comment: Hey, it is not clear what are you trying to achieve here. Since you are using a async block it is not save to return a parameter. It will never get the latest value you set to self.message.

Comment: " It will never get the latest value you set to self.message"  it what i am going to resolve

Comment: Okay, my question is do are you doing with the return value of that method. In case of async execution you need to use the completion block rather than to have function return a value.

Comment: Your `showMessage` function cannot return the value. You have to adopt the completion handler pattern there, too. Also, it's probably not prudent to be updating properties here. Just pass back the message as the parameter to your completion handler closure.